# Remove Duplicates From BindingList

Tags: c#, distinct, ienumerable, enumerable, bindinglist

Does BindingList have any solution to remove duplicate elements? I've tried:

```
 BindingList<Account> accounts = new BindingList<Account>();

 accounts.add(new Account("username", "password"));
 accounts.add(new Account("username", "password"));

 accounts = accounts.Distinct();
```

The above does not work as Distinct is returning `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` and not `BindingList<T>`

Comment: why don't you ensure they are unique first?

Comment: @DanielA.White the accounts are loaded from a text file, and there is a possibility duplicate entries may be entered by the user. Is there a benefit to checking first?

Comment: you could load them in to a dictionary/hashset.

Comment: They need to be in a BindingList. The BindingList is the DataSource to a DataGridView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a Constructor which takes an `IList<T>` and you can convert an `Enumerable<T>` [to a `List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
BindingList<Account> distinctAccounts = new BindingList<Account>(accounts.Distinct().ToList());
```

As [King King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679602/king-king) points out [Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses the default equality comparer

> The default equality comparer, Default, is used to compare values of
>   the types that implement the IEquatable generic interface. To
>   compare a custom data type, you need to implement this interface and
>   provide your own GetHashCode and Equals methods for the type.

Comment: This doesn't remove the duplicates. Doing a count on the elements after Distinct shows the same element count, even though duplicates exist.

Comment: @Torra it's because your `Account` class has not overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode`

Comment: @KingKing Totally forgot about doing this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (var a in accounts
    .ToLookup(x => new { x.Username, x.Password })
    .SelectMany(x => x.Skip(1))
    .ToArray())
{
    accounts.Remove(a);
}
```